# Weird bounding box on header Image link

Tags: html, css

i'm working On a website for a client, and I've hit a snag. I don't quite know how to fix this one and google searching has done me no help.

I've got a nav as seen on [This Site](https://dva-duo.c9users.io/index.html). If you hover over the logo to the top left, it behaves as a link, thus completing my desired goal. But, if you hover a few pixels below the image, no link. No cursor change or anything. Which is good, until you go down beyond that, in which there is a bit of space where you can hover to find the same link as the above image. This is not good, though I can't find a way to remove this without removing the  tag, which defeats the purpose anyway. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few hours of looking around other people's codes (bootstrap, materialize, etc) I found that changing the `position` and `display` values to `absolute` and `inline-block` of the link, it would make the link wrap the image. Hopefully this'll help anyone who had this weird problem too.

Answer (score 1):

Style them correctly.

```
a {
  cursor: default;
}

img {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

**OR** (Sass)

```
 a {
   cursor: default;
     img {
       cursor: pointer;
     }   
 }
```

Comment: While this does work, it doesn't disable the clickability of the link itself

Comment: well you can fix the with jquery `$('a').on('click', function(e){ e.preventDefault() });`

Comment: I'm trying to minimize my use of javascript to keep the load times down, though props for creativity

Comment: You can't change click functionality with `css`.

Comment: I know, what I want to do is get rid of it. I mean, It shouldn't be there anyways. It's the <a> tag itself that is making those 12 px of clickable-ness. I don't know why it's showing up there and not just wrapping the image tag.

Comment: Open up the developer tools and take a peek